# Java. Как сделать картинку полупрозрачной

Tags: java

есть команда

`gr.drawImage(img,250,250,null);`

как сделать что бы картинка отрисовывалась полупрозрачной?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать AlphaComposite

```
Composite comp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER , 0.5f);
gr.setComposite(comp);
```